# Isolate sub-string non-greedy?

Tags: javascript, regex, non-greedy

**Given strings such as:**

```
foo/**hello**/baré 
foo/crazy/**hello**/baré 
**hello**/crazy/baré
```

For each line, **how to isolate `hello` (the text between the `**`) via a JS  ?** (regex ? search)

(the output wanted for each line is `hello`)

---

So far, I fails there: `.*?\*\*(.*?)\*\*.*?` => `$1` gives me :

```
hello/baré 
hello/baré 
hello/crazy/baré
```

Comment: Are you using replace to get your output? Then the last `.*?` has to be greedy to match the end of the string. If you use match with your regex, it should work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an expression that matches any character except *:

```js
const inputs = [
  'foo/**hello**/baré',
  'foo/crazy/**hello**/baré',
  '**hello**/crazy/baré'
];

inputs.forEach(input => {
  const matches = input.match(/.*\*\*([^*]+)\*\*.*/);
  console.log(matches[1]);
});
```

Comment: The output wanted for each line is `hello`. According to my test, your answer doesn't do it.

Comment: I added an executable code snippet that prints "hello" to the console 3 times :-)

Comment: Oh. you use `.match()`.

Answer (score 2):

With a word, just use `\w`:

```
\*+(\w+)\*+
```

[Demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/h1vxdF/1)

If you want specifically 2 `*` just do

```
\*{2}(\w+)\*{2}
```

If you have a sentence or a paragraph or mixed characters, search for characters other than the starting and ending delimiters:

```
\*{2}([^*]+)\*{2}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I took your idea of `{2}` :D